# Specific flow in navigation controller pop view

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have 4 different views (a,b,c,d). User can go from:

```
a->b,
b->c ,b->d 
c->b ,b->d 
d-> c, d->b
```

To load a new view I use navitaion controller push view. 
My question what is the best solution to handle back button in order to make it always work like this:

```
d->c
c->b
b->a
```

regardless of all prior view controller pushes.

In the other words user makes the following sequence of transitions:
(ie.a->b->c->b->c->d->c) but when he presses back button I want him to see screen B, not previously pushed D.

I know how to solve it in ugly ways but I expect something more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UINavigationController supports popping back to a specific view controller through the popToViewController:animated method...

> Pops view controllers until the specified view controller is at the top of the navigation stack.
>
> - (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated

[Official Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

I would however recommend rethinking your navigation hierarchy.  The Apple Human Interface guidelines recommend following a structured and consistent navigation scheme.  Jumping between controllers can be confusing for the user.